# 3 byte array-for time format {Hour}{Minute}{Second}

Tags: c

I am reading system time(Register: TM11), and I want to get minute data from system time.
system time is in this data format = 3 bytes:{Hour}{Minute}{Second}

**I am not sure, how to extract "minute" data, using array format, C code as below.** 
In my C code below, i use read_register function for reading system time, and use pointer `(byte*)&systime[1])`  to extract "minute". -not sure this is correct way to do so.

let's say, time now is 07:48:29 AM then, TM11 will show 07,48,29 
I want to extract "48", which is minute, from TM11. 
time interval: 15 minute.
Time Passed = 48 % 15 = 3 minute.

Putting this calculation in the C,

```
byte systime[2]; 
//declare "systime" variable as 3 byte array and to store TM11 //

byte time_interval = 15; //time interval is 15 minute 

read_register (TM11,(byte*)&systime[1]); 
//let's say read data value of TM11 is, 07:48:29 AM
//"read_register"function is to read the value of TM11 register
//(byte*)&systime[1] =try to point "minute" in TM11 register, systime[1]=48
//I am not sure whether hour will store in systime[0], minute will store in systime[1],//

elaps_time = systime[1] % time_interval; 
//elapsed time calculation = 48 % 15 = 3
```

Comment: btw, your `systime` is a 2 byte array in your example. can you elaborate more on what the issue is?

Comment: If you want the minute portion of a 3-byte array, you need to get `array[1]` — whether the order is hour-minute-second or second-minute-hour.  What's the complication?  It seems odd to read 3 bytes into `&systime[1]` which writes one byte in the last byte of your array of two bytes, and then tramples over whatever happens to follow the array in memory.  That's not good.  Use `byte systime[3];` and `read_register(TM11, systime);`.  The cast from `byte *` to `byte *` seems unnecessary too — so I omitted it in my suggested version.

Comment: @khuynh, system time I read is in 3 byte format: {Hour}{Minute}{Second}, so show 07,48,29 In my C code below, i use read_register function for reading system time, and use pointer (byte*)&systime[1]) to extract "minute". -not sure this is correct way to do so.

Comment: If reading register TM11 writes to 3 bytes, you _must_ make sure you pass it space enough to write 3 bytes.  When it is done, you will have the three values in sequence — presumably `systime[0]` containing the hours, `systime[1]` containing minutes, and `systime[2]` containing the second seconds.  You didn't, and can't, tell the register to do something special like 'only the minutes value'; it will always write 3 bytes.  You might think about identifying which embedded system you're working with (add a tag to your question too, if there's one available). You may find specialists who can help.